# How to hide extra overflow part of this angled css ribbon?

Tags: css

How to hide extra part of this angled css ribbon?

[image]

**Fork this jsfiddle to play** http://jsfiddle.net/PjnmQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified you code and added a overflow: hidden to the box

http://jsfiddle.net/aNmvc/4/