# How to give Wrap-Around look to this angled css ribbon?

Tags: css

[Camille-ascencio-parvy-lemoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039883/camille-ascencio-parvy-lemoine) has given [answer to my old question to make ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084171/how-to-hide-extra-overflow-part-of-this-angled-css-ribbon) but now I need to make the ribbon flip like this

[image]

Play with JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aNmvc/8/

This question I only asked to make Flip corner. Other things of ribbon are not needed for that answer

Comment: if you want it to look exactly like the image you provided (with bevel, white glow and little flipped corner) you'll have to use an image.

Comment: @ptriek - This question I only asked to make Flip corner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a 45 degree responsive ribbon with folded corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128872/how-can-i-make-a-45-degree-responsive-ribbon-with-folded-corner)